# vector of object all the same object after adding separate objects to it

Tags: c++, vector

So I'm adding a bunch of objects to a vector inside of my class. I am able to add everything, or it seems, just fine, but when I go to print the contents of the vector everything is the very last object that I added. Why is that? This is what it looks like when I add

`this->packages.push_back(mc);`

This is what it looks like when I call the object I want to print

`std::cout << truck.packages[1]->getTrack() << endl;`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, vectors seem pretty straight forward on adding and removing items.

If I need to add anything else, please let me know.

```
  std::cout << truck.packages[1]->getTrack() << endl;
  std::cout << truck.packages[2]->getTrack() << endl;
```

`Output:  11111
          11111`

This is how I create the object

```
if(type == 0){
  Letter *letter = new Letter();
  letter->setType("Letter");
  letter->setWeight(weight);
  letter->setTrack(track);
  price = letter->cost();
  letter->setPrice(price);

  this->packages.push_back(letter);

  truckWeight = this->getGross() + (weight / 16);
  this->setGross(truckWeight);

  this->numPackages++;

  delete letter;
```

This is letter.cpp

```
Letter::Letter()
{
  this->type = "Letter";
  this->price = 0.0;
  this->weight = 0;
  this->trackingNumber = 0;
}

double Letter::cost()
{
  int weight = this->getWeight();
  if(weight > 32)
    return 0.0;
  else
    return (0.5 * weight);
}
```

This is letter.h

```
class Letter: public Package{`enter code here`

public:
  Letter();

  double cost();
};
```

Made it with Letter. It doesn't matter which object I use. They all do the same thing

Comment: `std::cout << truck.packages[1]->getTrack() << endl;` - are you always using the index 1?

Comment: no, I was using a for loop 1 to the size of it. Still would get the same thing

Comment: post your code for mc

Comment: care to elaborate where `mc` comes from? Are you allocating a new object for *each* item *before* the push_back? Please, *please* post code that reproduces the problem. You have that code; we *don't*. My crystal ball tells me if you debugged this you'd see all the pointers in your vector are the *same* object pointer.

Comment: The code as it stands, does not show any error, you need to provide more of your code

Comment: working on it give me a second

Comment: Um.. `delete letter;` ? Didn't you just add that to the container? And can you clarify one more thing, Show the *real* declaration of the `packages` member of `truck`. I've a feeling you're using pointers to facilitate virtual derivation and polymorphic override of `cost()`, and seeing that declaration will solidify that theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have UB in your code. You have a `vector` of `Letter*`s. When you `push_back` these `Letter*`s, the vector just makes a copy of these pointers. Once you call `delete` on the original `Letter*`, these vector elements are now dangling. You can handle this in two ways :

1. Make `package` a `vector<Letter>` instead of `vector<Letter*>`. Now, you just happily `push_back`(or, preferable, `emplace_back`) `Letter`s.
2. If you must use pointers, use `unique_ptr`(or some other smart pointer). So, `package` would be `vector<unique_ptr>`. When the vector gets destroyed, the `unique_ptr`s will take care of memory deallocation.

If you don't want to use a smart pointer, you will have to manage the `delete`s yourself. So, if `package` is a member of `MyAwesomePackage`(no pun intended), you would do this in the destructor:

```
MyAwesomePackage::~MyAwesomePackage()
{
///Other destruction
for(auto * letter : package)
  delete letter;
}
```

Comment: if i'm using the pointers, how would i go about deleting them after use if i'm getting errors with using unique_ptr

Comment: @kevorski You will have to handle that on your own. Since `package` is a class member, you can correctly deallocate those pointers the class destructor.

Comment: so when I'm finished with the vector I would just traverse through the vector and call delete on them, and in the destructor just make it to null?

Answer (score 0):

While you don't show the declaration of the vector, your usage in this statement:

```
std::cout << truck.packages[1]->getTrack() << endl;
```

shows that you're not building a vector of objects, but a vector of **pointers to** objects.

If the vector contains only a pointer, and you modify the object referenced by this pointer after pushing the pointer into the vector, you will see the new value when you access it later through the pointer in the vector.

You are probably doing something like this:

```
std::vector<Package*> packages;
mc = new Package;
mc->setFoo(1);
packages.push_back(mc);
mc->setFoo(2);
packages.push_back(mc);
```

You now have two pointers to the same object in the vector. Since you modified the object after the first `push_back()` call, you will see the new value of the object when you access either element in the vector.

To make this work, you will need to either store actual objects in the vector:

```
std::vector<Package> packages;
```

or allocate a new `Package` object each time before you push the pointer into the vector.

After seeing the full code, your problem is a slight variation of this: You're deleting the object after pushing a pointer to it into the vector. So the vector contains pointers to objects that have been deleted, which leads to undefined behavior. What is probably happening in your test case is that when you allocate a new object after deleting the previous one, you're getting a pointer to the same memory again. That's why it looks like all values are the same. But even that is "random" and completely unspecified behavior.